# zipping all files specified in a text file and then deleting them

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I'm trying to add each file, specified one per line, into a file named files.zip. The directory structure of each file specified should remain as is. After the file listed in files.txt is added to files.zip it should be deleted, but never the directories.

The structure of the text file is one file per line:

```
/file2.png
/data/example.png
/data2/more.png
/music/test.ogg
```

I have files.txt in the `/` directory I'm running the zip command from.

Background Information: I'm running Debian with the package zip installed. I can only get manually specified files\folders to zip (ex: $ zip -r /files.zip /), but not by specifying an external list from a txt file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Please show the relevant code and state where you are having problems. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapfile -t files <files.txt &&
zip /files.zip "${files[@]}" &&
rm -f -- "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

## `tee` command

Use `tee` command that allows to pipe stdin to many other command and|or files.

```sh
cat files.txt| tee >( 
 while read line; do 
  [[ -f $line ]] && 
  echo 'rm -f $line' && 
  echo $line deleted ; 
 done
) | zip -@ files.zip
```

Explanation:

- `cat files.txt`

  - pipe all filenames to stdout`
- `| tee >( ... ) | zip -@ files.zip`

  - send filenames both to the `rm` command and to `zip`
- `while read line; do ...; done`

  - execute line by line
- `[[ -f $line ]] && rm -f $line`

  - remove files only